# Selecting first result in RSS feed using XPath and FeedWordpress

Tags: xml, wordpress, xpath, rss

I am using a plugin on WordPress called "FeedWordPress" and having it post from feeds from an audio website. The plugin has a spot to input info from an RSS feed to a custom field in the theme. It works but since my feed has two media:content tags it adds in two results and I only want the first one.

When I test the expression $(media:content/@url) it shows two results since there are to media:content urls.

[testing expression in plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2lTI.png)

The following are the results:

```
•   result[0] = https://audioboom.(com)/boos/4394781-10-re-shooting-and-re-imagining-suicide-squad.mp3?source=rss&stitched=1
•   result[1] = https://d15mj6e6qmt1na.cloudfront.(net)/i/20924438
```

I have the first one working going to my mp3 custom field BUT it adds the second one as a link under it. And resultv1 I need for my featured image.

[result of expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LH8XY.png)

Note: I put the domains in () since I don't have enough rep to add 2 links inside this post.

Maybe some XPath experts might know of an expression that may work in the plugin?

Comment: Try `media:content[1]/@url` or `(media:content/@url)[1]`

Comment: The results of that trial did not work and the results are below:

media:content[1]/@url
result[0] = media:content[1]/@url

(media:content/@url)[1]
result[0] = (media:content/@url)[1]

Comment: @srikanth-nakka I noticed you have been very vocal on some of these XPath related questions. Could you help me in this?